# Magento: {{var payment}} showing two cards in admin and emails

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

**Situation:**

We recently took a magento store live and when we got our domain setup properly our payment info started showing double entries for some reason. This double entry shows anywhere that payment info would normally show (customer account, admin order view, emails, and printed orders).

**Problem:**

What we see now is this:
[image: payment info as its currently showing]

**Credit Card**
Credit Card 1
Credit Card Type:   CardType
Credit Card Number:     xxxx-0000
Processed Amount:   $1XX.XX
Credit Card 2
Credit Card Type:   CardType
Credit Card Number:     xxxx-0000
Order was placed using USD

We are getting calls and emails from customers wanting to be sure we haven't charged them twice, but the payment only goes through once so I know the actual payment method (Authorize.net) is still working properly.

I'm not sure what would have caused this problem since the only change that was made was to stop running off IP when we pointed the domain. I want to get the original problem fixed, but if I can't then I need to know how to pull specific data out of {{var payment}} so that I can just show:
a.)Payment type
b.)[if credit card]Card type
c.)Payment amount

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an after_save of before_save payment event which is doing an additional save, that can be the problem here.

Comment: @JeffreydeGraaf, I haven't made any changes to the core code that would affect the default operation. It wasn't doing this before we pointed the domain. That said I am not sure of the best way to see if there is a before/after_save_payment event doing an additional save. I do know that orders are coming in as "processing" not as "new" which doesn't seem to be default behavoir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been experiencing the same problem.  (Magento Enterprise 1.13.02)  We tested on a clean installation and did not have the problem, and began to investigate.  Here's what we found, and how we fixed it:

The good news is, there is only a single charge -- it's just being displayed twice because of an 'if statement' unexpectedly returning true.

In this file:
/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Block/Authorizenet/Info/Cc.php

You will see function called getCards.  This part was causing the problem for us:

```
if ($this->getInfo()->getCcType() && $this->_isCheckoutProgressBlockFlag) {
        $cards[] = $this->getSpecificInformation();
    }
```

Specifically, getCcType was returning a value, where on a clean installation it was not.

In our case, we found an Order/Invoice Editor extension to be the source of the problem.  This one, specifically:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/re-authorize-order-editor-grid-manager-invoice-editor.html

Orders placed while this extension is enabled have credit card details (such as CcType, and the encrypted card number) saved in the database (sales_flat_order_payment).  Orders placed with this extension disabled do not.

We have contacted the developer for clarification, as we do not want the PCI compliance headache of storing encrypted credit card numbers.

We've disabled the extension for now, and it has solved our problem.  We could modify the above mentioned 'if statement' if we wanted to keep storing credit cards and display properly.

Hope this helps!